# What’s the best way to delete boost::thread object right after its work is complete?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I create `boost::thread` object with a `new` operator and continue without waiting this thread to finish its work:

```
void do_work()
{
    // perform some i/o work
}

boost::thread *thread = new boost::thread(&do_work);
```

I guess, it’s necessary to delete `thread` when the work is done. What’s the best way to this without explicitly waiting for thread termination?

Comment: Why dynamically create the thread?

Comment: @Martin York: Because I don’t want thread object to be destroyed after leaving the scope of the variable.

Comment: But if you just let it fall out of scope then you can't accesses it (and thus you leak). Not having accesses to means you can not do anything with it and the actual thread of execution is still alive anyway so it seem pointless. Note: You should practically **NEVER** have a RAW pointer like that.

Comment: @Martin York: I know this. Maybe it’s bad code example. Actually, i suppose pointer to thread object to be stored somewhere so i can delete it later. My question was how to delete it right after the thread is terminated, but it turned out to be possible to safely delete thread object before thread termination.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `boost::thread` object's lifetime and the native thread's lifetime are unrelated. The `boost::thread` object can go out of scope at any time.

From the `boost::thread` class [documentation](http://www.pdc.kth.se/training/Talks/C++/boost/libs/thread/doc/thread.html)

> Just as the lifetime of a file may be different from the lifetime of an iostream object which represents the file, the lifetime of a thread of execution may be different from the  thread object which represents the thread of execution. In particular, after a call to join(), the thread of execution will no longer exist even though the thread object continues to exist until the end of its normal lifetime. The converse is also possible; if a thread object is destroyed without join() having first been called, the thread of execution continues until its initial function completes.

**Edit**: If you just need to start a thread and never invoke `join`, you can use the thread's constructor as a function:

```
    // Launch thread.
boost::thread(&do_work);
```

However, I don't suggest you do that, even if you think you're sure the thread will complete before `main()` does.

Comment: Thank you. I’m new to Boost Threads, so the problem was in my misunderstanding of how it works.

Comment: As far as I know this is how native threads work on most platforms anyways. So unless the thread destructor called join(), which would be a mess in presence of exceptions, it is only a normal consequence.

Answer (score 13):

You can use

```
boost::thread t(&do_work);
t.detach();
```

Once the thread is detached it is no longer owned by the `boost::thread` object; the object can be destroyed and the thread will continue to run.  The `boost::thread` destructor also calls `detach()` if the object owns a running thread, so letting `t` get destroyed will have the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use boost::shared_ptr, so you won't take care when to delete thread object.

```
boost::shared_ptr<boost::threaｄ> thread(new boost::thread(&do_work));
```

Comment: How does this thread object get deleted when `do_work` finishes?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [thread interruption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.interruption).

[This article](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html) is good also.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html