# pure virtual method called in thread of concrete class

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, pure-virtual

I have a problem with virtual methods in C++ on a multithreading context (Linux).

This next example points out my problem:

```
class Base {

};

class Concrete1: public Base {    //define pure virtual function
    virtual void func() = 0;
}; 

class Concrete2: public Concrete1 {     //override of virtual func
    void func() {}

    void run(){
        //....
        pthread_create(&handle, NULL, Concrete2::thread, static_cast<void*>(this));
    }

    static void* thread(void arg*){
        Concrete2 *ptr = static_cast<Concrete2*>(arg);
        //Concrete1 *ptr = static_cast<Concrete2*>(arg);    // same error 

        while(1){ 
           //....
           ptr->func()
        }
    }
};

int main(){
  Concrete2 obj;
  obj.run();

  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

When the line `ptr->func()` is executed, the following error appears:

```
pure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception
```

Can someone tell me why the pure virtual method is being called instead of the overrided method?

Comment: Where do you declare `func` as being virtual?

Comment: @G.M. Doesn't matter, it is by virtue of being called the same, however the override keyword might help narrow it down if it is not.

Comment: I think related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381757/c-terminate-called-without-an-active-exception

Comment: What is `Concrete2`?

Comment: Please include how you're creating the objects and calling `run`.

Comment: There is a lot missing from your code, for example construction and execution. Really, for this kind of questions, you need to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise all we can do is guessing.

Comment: What's `Concrete::thread` in the call to `pthread_create`?  Please update your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated the post again. Sorry for not providing mcve. The classes from my project are way more complex. This is just an example to show you where my code fails.

Answer (score 1):

`Concrete2` is created on the stack and is destroyed as soon as `run` is called.

The spawned thread does not keep `obj` alive.

Your `thread` function is trying to dereference a destroyed object, aka a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), which constitutes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Instead of creating the object statically, I created dinamically, and it works.