# How to delete boost thread object when thread itself terminates?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

When threads are added to boost::thread_group like:

```
boost::thread_group my_threads;
boost::thread *t = new boost::thread( &someFunc );
my_threads.add_thread(th);
```

all the created boost::thread objects are deleted only when `my_threads` object is out of scope. But my program main thread spawns a lot of threads while execution. So if about 50 threads are already done, about **1,5Gb** of memory is used by program and this memory is freed only on main process termination.

The question is: **How to delete these boost::thread object when thread function is finished ?!**

Comment: I believe this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970818/whats-the-best-way-to-delete-boostthread-object-right-after-its-work-is-compl

Comment: @Naveen, I do really need a wrapper that can interrupt all pooled children threads when main thread asks for it. In question you linked they recommend just create a thread and detach boost::thread object from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do sth like this, but mind synchronization (it is better to use shared pointer to boost::thread_group instead of reference, unless you are sure, that thread group will live long enough):

```
void someFunc(..., boost::thread_group & thg, boost::thread * thisTh)
{
  // do sth

  thg.remove_thread(thisThr);
  delete thisTh; // we coud do this as thread of execution and boost::thread object are quite independent
}

void run()
{
  boost::thread_group my_threads;
  boost::thread *t = new boost::thread(); // invalid handle, but we need some memory placeholder, so we could pass it to someFunc
  *t = boot::thread(
    boost::bind(&someFunc, boost::ref(my_threads), t)
  );
  my_threads.add_thread(t);
  // do not call join
}
```

You  could also check at_thread_exit() function.

Anyway, boost::thread objects should not weight 30 MB.

Comment: thanks for the solution. While was waiting the answer, also thought of sending the boost::thread pointer to the thread function.

Comment: I'm using **htop** on 2 **Gentoo** machines and 1 **FreeBSD**. On Gentoo machines the **VIRT** column of htop shows ~450MB when there are 15 threads created and running. On FreeBSD with same number of threads the VIRT column shows ~65300KB. I'm confused

Comment: I realized that was looking at wrong column. **RES** shows about **33mb** on all machines. Btw, you call `thg.remove_thread(thisThr)` in thread without using a mutex. Is it safe?!

Comment: Documentation of boost 1.31 states that _All thread_group member functions are thread-safe, except destruction._ This sentence is absent in boost 1.49 documentation, however, there is no mention in _Breaking Changes_ that this changed. I would assume, that thread_group is thread-safe.