# Is it safe to re-assign detached boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost

For example

```
boost::thread th = boost::thread(a_lengthy_function);
th.detach();
th = boost::thread(another_function);
```

Will first thread be canceled or affected by second thread?

Comment: Side note: consider using `std::thread`

Comment: Consider what detaching a thread does. It'd be really idiosyncratic if the handles still affected a detached thread in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from boost [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.detach):

> A thread can be detached by explicitly invoking the detach() member function on the boost::thread object. In this case, the boost::thread object ceases to represent the now-detached thread, **and instead represents Not-a-Thread**.
>
> thread() noexcept;Effects:**Constructs a boost::thread instance that refers to Not-a-Thread**

so a detached thread is the same thing as a default constructed thread. So, yes, you can safely move-assign to a default constructed thread, and the answer to your second question is no, the two threads are totally unrelated.

FYI, the same applies to std::thread as well ...

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't matter at all.

As mentioned by André Caron:

> The boost::thread object's lifetime and the native thread's lifetime are unrelated. The boost::thread object can go out of scope at any time.

from [What’s the best way to delete boost::thread object right after its work is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970818/what-s-the-best-way-to-delete-boostthread-object-right-after-its-work-is-compl)